# sorting/filter specific images from mysql

Tags: mysql, image, sorting, filtering

I have a MySQL table to store images of models/actors, every models/actors can add 10 images, now what I want when I am showing images on their profile page, I want to show 2 images first then some text from other table, then again 2 images then again some text.

I don't need to show all the images of a specific models/actors all together. How can I achieve that?

Right now when i am retrieving images, its showing all the images all together.

[image: I have added image of my table.]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: Hello, As I m not very good in php/myql, i m just trying with this code ...

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM model_image where es_id={$_GET['es_id']}";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the code used and the html result view. Have a look at [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have sorted out with Limit and offset, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have sort out with Limit and offset in query.